# Reading a UML Class Diagram from Java

Tags: java, uml, reverse-engineering

I'm developing a reverse engineering tool for my final year project. In this project, i'm trying to read a uml diagram from java and analyze the relationship between the classes. I want to know whether there is a standard file format for UML diagrams. According to my requirement i should be able to read that file format using java and extract details about the relationship details between classes.

I know that there are many tools available to draw UML diagrams. I want to know whether they share a common standard internally so that i can read that file from java and extract details from it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a standard maintained by the OMG called [XML Metadata Interchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Metadata_Interchange).
Basically it takes all the UML data and represents it in XML, ie. all the entitites, relationships, multiplicity, etc. are all represented as XML tags and attributes defined according to the Schema.

Now, as this information is represented in XML, you can quite easily parse it and extract the necessary information for your project in Java.

The last part of your question asks who supports this standard. [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa140339%28v=office.10%29.aspx), [IBM](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rsarthlp/v8/topic/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/texpmod.html) and [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/uml_tool_guide/projects_and_teams/exporttoxmi.html) all support it for a start.

Information about the structure of an XMI document can be found in the [standard](http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.4.1/PDF/).

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the quick reply. Is there a way to get information about tags and their attributes in this XMI file. Do the above mentioned tools share a common set of tags and attributes.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a link to the XMI standard document. In particular you are interested in chapter 7 "XMI Document and Schema Design Principles"

Comment: ...and you need to take a look into the UML2.x Specification itself, of course. It defines the meta classes which are used as XML tags in XMI.